# iOS - Album metadata displayed incorrectly

Tags: iphone, itunes

In the Music app on my iPhone, one of the Albums is showing the name of the album before the song title (unlike all the others). The album shows up correctly in iTunes, ruling out the case of incorrect metadata. I have tried editing the title but without luck.

What could possibly be the reason for this discrepancy and how do I resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things get messed up. Have you considered removing it from the library on a computer - manually fixing the metadate using iTunes or another program and then re-adding the songs to your library?

Before removing it - look for flags like “compilation” and “composer” to try disabling that.

Also - you will want to check how your iOS library syncs - whether it’s iCloud / Apple Music / or a more manual sync. Things could need a resync if you make changes in iTunes off the iOS device.

Since it seems you already tried editing and syncing you might need to remove it entirely and sync to remove the songs and add them correctly.